# Curl PHP GET request - 504

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm trying to do a curl php get request to display some json data on page.

The issue that I'm having here is that I keep getting hit with a 504 gateway timeout.

So I was hopping to get a second pair of eyes on my code to make sure I'm not doing anything silly or missing something.

```
// get request
$ch = curl_init('http://*****');
$token = '****';

// Return Data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

//User Agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Fiddler');

//Set your auth headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: ****:8090',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
    ));

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

// print details of request on page
echo 'info:' . $info ;

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I don't know that we can help you with this. From a functionality standpoint, your code looks fine. You'll have to contact the support for that site to see what else can be done.

Comment: @Machavity I thought that might be the case. Just wanted a second opinion first. Thanks

Comment: Your code mostly works. Have you verified connectivity from your server to the remote? Do they respond to requests on port 80 or 443 from your server? Do they respond with an invalid request if you make your request without the token?

Comment: I would step through one thing at a time - make sure your script works against any old server on port 80, and then make one change at a time until you know exactly where things are breaking down.

Comment: Hi @LucasKrupinski I tested the script on another server works fine was the server had to contact the host to get them to authorize the port through there firewalls

Comment: Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that the host's firewalls were blocking requests to certain ports and I had to get them to unblock the ports in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in headers, Host must contain only the hostname `Host: *****:8090`.

It must be like this one : `Host: google.com`.

The port must be specified using `curl_setopt ()`, like this:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8090);
```

Comment: adding to @Kark92's answer, you're also trying to echo out an array ($data), but that is of no use until you get your data back in the first place.

Comment: Tried no difference sorry